# Invalid signature of JWT token - Azure + Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, access-token, azure-authentication

I am using Azure AD for users authentication for spring boot application. I have created one application to get the access token for the logged in user (token-creator application). In this application '/token' API read the access token from the @**RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient** and returns back the same token as response.

Then I have to use the returned token as bearer token for the rest APIs for the another application with same client id and same configurations.

But when I use that access token, it gave me the following error :

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

I checked the JWT token in jwt.io, it says that invalid signature.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Access Token - JWT.io - Invalid Signature]

[image]

Comment: Can you parse the token and provide a screenshot?

Comment: Added the screenshot.

Comment: Do you want to call ms graph api?

Comment: As you said that the token is failed to decode in jwt.io, so could you pls add details on how to generate the token such as your code or sample you followed.

Comment: @CarlZhao, yes I am using MS Graph APIs.

Comment: @Tiny-wa, I am following this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory. Also in controller I am using the below code :

`
 @Controller
 public class MyController {
     @GetMapping("/authorized-client")
     public String authorizedClient(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("login-client") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
         return oAuth2AuthorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
     }
 }
`

Comment: Thanks for resposne, and the totorial only demo how to secure the application with Spring Boot classes and annotations but without showing how to generate access token and call api. I recommend you to refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample). If you aren't willing to generate certificate, you can ignore the configurations about server.ssl in application.properties and use http instead of https. I learn springboot+azure ad with this sample, hope it help you too.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny-wa, I will go through it and will try to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Your access token is for calling Microsoft Graph API.

However, access token for Microsoft Graph does not need to be validated by your code, because the Graph API server side will validate it.

In other words, Graph's access token will never pass verification in your code.

If the access token is to call your own API (rather than call Microsoft Graph), you need to specify the scope as `[CLIENT_ID of the API app registration]/.default` rather than `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. Then the access token can be validated successfully.

Comment: I am using the same MS Graph APIs to validate the access token. 
When I create the access token from Postman tool, it works very well. But when I create access token from java code (either using different spring boot application with same client id and configs or MSAL4J), it is giving the "Invalid Signatue" error.

For creating token using postman I follow the steps from : https://www.digitalonus.com/securing-a-restful-api-using-spring-boot-and-microsofts-azure-active-directory/

Comment: @sagarg What value did you put for `scope` in postman?

Comment: @sagarg I don't understand what you mean by "When I create the access token from Postman tool, it works very well".  Is that you create the access token in postman and then put the access token into your code for validation and it can call microsoft Graph successfully without getting `Invalid signature` error?

Comment: I am using postman to check the rest APIs calls. I want to secure these rest APIs with access(bearer) token. For creating that access token, I tried multiple ways like :
1. Created a separate spring boot application (token-creator) - which takes user credentials and create token. It creates the token, but when I am using that token to access rest APIs from main application, it gives the invalid signature error for that token.

Used : @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2AuthorizedClient

Comment: 2. Simple java application with MSAL4J library - Same error for this also.

Used : 
 A. PublicClientApplication
 B. AuthenticationContext

3. Postman - When I am creating the access token using postman, it gives me the valid signature token and then I am trying this token with main application's rest APIs it is working as expected.

So like the postman, I have to generate the access token using java (with valid signature for JWT)

Comment: @sagarg When you parse the Microsoft Graph access token (generated in postman) in https://jwt.io, it will show valid Signature?  Can you provide a screenshot for this token?

Comment: Yes, it gives the valid JWT. Attached the screenshot.

Comment: @sagarg It's not for Microsoft Graph. See the `aud`. As I mentioned, Microsoft Graph access token is validated by Microsoft Graph side. You cannot make it pass validation in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Allen Wu, I have tried with simple Java, and it is working as expected. Now I will try for web application. Many thanks.

Comment: @sagarg That's great! Keep me posted and let me know if my answer is helpful.

Comment: I am trying to apply the custom values for the below properties from application.properties file in spring boot application, but the application is not using these properties, it uses the default values.

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secrete=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-name=azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.provider=azure-oauth-provider

Comment: @sagarg It's related to your own configuration and environment. Please check if you update the file correctly. I can hardly provide help on such an issue:(